# Gap whitespace between items

Tags: html, css, sass

I have setup a grid system and they are almost behaving as expected.

The problem is there is a big gab between the columns

[image]

I tried setting the grid-column-gap but it seems unresponsive. Note that im using scss, though i tried changing it back to css but that gave the same result.

```css
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 1rem;
    grid-gap: 1rem;
    justify-items: center;
    
    .language {
        width: 360px;
        height: 150px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
        background: white;
        padding: 1rem;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: black;
        box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 1px rgb(228, 228, 228);
    }

    p {
        color: red;
        
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="language">
      <h3>LanguageContainer</h3>
      <p>Description</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The whole container is 100% width by default, and so the columns each take a third of the full width available. However, the items within have a fixed width, so you have a large gap.

Comment: omg you're the man! Thank you, that makes alot sense.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Niet the dark Absol.

> The whole container is 100% width by default, and so the columns each take a third of the full width available. However, the items within have a fixed width, so you have a large gap. – Niet the Dark Absol 54 mins ago

Simply by putting a width to my container fixed it.

```
.container {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 1rem;
grid-gap: 1rem;
width: 70%;
justify-items: center;

.language {
    width: 360px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(214, 214, 214);
    background: white;
    padding: 1rem;
    text-align: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px 1px rgb(228, 228, 228);
}

p {
    color: red;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0fr);
```

Now you can adjust the gap with this:

```
grid-gap: 10px;
```